how spread spectrum can change a selective channel to flat
Dr. Morelos-Zaragoza in his book: The Art of Error Correcting Codes, 2ed, on page 1, says:
"Usually, the channel is assumed to be such that samples of an additive noise process
are added to the modulated symbols (in their equivalent complex baseband representation).
The noise samples are assumed to be independent from the source symbols. This model is
relatively easy to track mathematically and includes additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN)
channels, ﬂat Rayleigh fading channels, and binary symmetric channels (BSC). The case of
frequency-selective channels can also be included, as techniques such as spread-spectrum and multicarrier modulation (MCM) effectively transform them into either AWGN channels or ﬂat Rayleigh fading channels."
I understand all of the above paragraph but the spread-spectrum! I wonder how a spread spectrum can change a frequency-selective to a flat-fading channel.

Perhaps consider the case where the carrier is fixed and the noise is spread-spectrum

The de-spreading process in the receiving side of a spread-spectrum system has the effect of spreading the frequency-dependent aspects of the channel over the entire channel bandwidth.

more philosophical than technical! I am still thinking ...
